# How to fix error 533 on wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, server, web-hosting, fault, memberpress

I have recently created a wordpress website to showcase my photography. This website uses the memberpress plugin and users subscribe for a membership in order to see the photos.
Recently my web hosting company has contacted me to let me know the site is generating faults. They are going to suspend my account if I don't fix it. I have tried optimising the site, all images have been compressed and I am using a caching plugin. I am only running 4 or 5 plugins on the site and using the divi theme.
I have tried everything but cannot work out what is causing the faults on the website. When working on the site I am quite often receiving "Error 533 origin response error".

Any help with what may be causing these faults would be much appreciated.

Comment: What webhosting do you use?

Comment: I'm getting the same "533 Origin Response Error" after trying to install an SSL certificate.